# Where does Odo fit in the chain of command?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Odo doesn't have a conventional rank, but he is still able to give orders. Does he only have authority over his security men and non-crew members?

Obviously Sisko and Kira have seniority over him, but I assume that Bashir, Dax, and Worf also do.

Because he doesn't have an official rank, can anyone, even a lowly crewman, tell Odo what to do? How does that work?

Comment: Odo has no rank within Starfleet as he is not a member of that organisation. He is chief of security of the station as part of the Bajoran administrative staff, therefore reporting to Major Kira.

Comment: @IanF1: that sounds like an answer: you should post it as such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Odo's rank and position are something of an anomaly.

He doesn't appear to have a *formal* rank within the militia other than Head of DS9 Station Security, and he certainly doesn't have a Starfleet rank. He does, however act as ***Head of the Security Department*** (on behalf of both the Federation and Bajorans) which means that he can order around both Starfleet and Bajoran Security Officers *with the authority of* the station's commander (Sisko) and *with the authority of* the ranking Bajoran (Major Kira) who also happens to be his line officer.

This seems to be backed up by Garak

> **TAIN:** *Well, that's unfortunate. I see no further use for Mister Odo. Terminate him.*
>
> **GARAK:** *On the other hand, **he is a member of the Bajoran militia and an officer on Deep Space Nine.** We may not wish to provoke the
> Federation by killing him.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Die is Cast](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/467.htm)</sup></sub>

And his [official profile](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/odo#sthash.GUccFqJK.dpuf) on the StarTrek.com website

> **Position:** *Security chief, Bajoran Militia, DS9 detachment*

Oh, and don't call him Constable, he doesn't much like it.

> **PRIMMIN:** *Yes, Constable.*
>
> **ODO:** *And don't call me Constable. I'm Chief of Security.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Move Along Home](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/410.htm)</sup></sub>

---

You may wish to note that this isn't the first time a low-ranked officer has been given [direct control of a department](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Kim_(Star_Trek)).