# Who uses combadges other than Starfleet and Bajoran Militia?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, communication

In TNG and DS9, Starfleet members and soldiers/officers in the Bajoran militia use long distance communicators shaped like the symbols of the organizations they serve attached to their uniforms- do military/security forces of any other nations use similar devices?

Comment: Does Odo count?  He appears to be wearing a Bajoran militia outfit, complete with combadge, but he's *not* a member of the Bajoran militia.  He just looks like that because he was mimicking the Bajoran scientist who found him.  (Side-note: always found it odd that his combadge, which is not part of him or it probably wouldn't be functional, morphed with him somehow...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Odo [absolutely is a member of the Bajoran Militia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139617/20774)

Comment: @Valorum Not always - during the Cardassian occupation, Odo was still Chief of Security, which the Cardassians surely would not have allowed if he were a member of the Bajoran Militia (which they considered to be a terrorist organization).  He also retained that position when the Cardassians retook the station for a while - notably the only person allowed that leeway as all the Bajoran officers were kicked out.  In all that time though, he kept his Bajoran combadge.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman apparently he indeed morphed a functional combadge.

Answer (score 11):

The Klingons used a couple of different combadge styles.

This kind seen [several times in TNG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o4GJdHsRH0).
[image] [image]

And this from the film *Generations*.
[image]

---

Interestingly, the website Roddenberry.com (seller of 'officially licensed" Star Trek props and merchandise) sold [a set of '*alien combadges*'](https://web.archive.org/web/20090422031451/http:/www.roddenberry.com:80/alien-communicator-badge-kit.html).

> This is a 1:1 scale prop of five alien badges used on STAR TREK:  The Next Generation, Deep Space Nine, and Voyager.  This set includes the Klingon and Romulan badges, as well as badges used by alien races: Prytt, Angosian, Hierarchy and Ledosian.  The badge set also includes an attractive display plaque comes painted in a metallic finish.

[image]

Comment: So the badges cling on to the sleeve instead of the shirt?

Comment: The one from *Generations* looks like it's a repurposed Klingon elevator call button...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Klingons had to deal with 'low bidder wins the contract' as much as everyone else...

Comment: Are they "combadges of honor"?

Comment: At the end of this clip you can see a Klingon using his arm based com badge https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o4GJdHsRH0

Comment: @Mike - A fine addition to my answer. Cheers

Comment: their badges can cling-on anything